# how do i move my vertical text to the bottom left using html css?

Tags: html, css

im trying to move my hyper link to the bottom left of my webpage.
now, the hyperlink is at the top left of my webpage.

thank you in advance for everyone that comments :]

this is the line of code that i added to try to move my link down (failed):

`transform-origin: left bottom 0;`

```
{
  font-family : Times New Roman;
  font-weight : bold;
  font-size : 18px;
  color : #25374C;
  color : rgb(37, 55, 76);

  transform: rotate(270deg);
  transform-origin: left bottom 0;

  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 6px;
}

<p class="socials_email"><a href="mailto:sillygoose95@gmail.com?subject=Subject%20Content&amp;body=Body%20Content" style="text-decoration: none;">sillygoose95@gmail.com</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Position property only works on block level, so you have to specify the p tag as a block or inline-block depending on what you need, you can check the differences between them if you wish on w3schools, besides, the position relative refers to the parent position if available, but if not, then it refers to the document, so I recommend using absolute position, and you can read about the differences on CSS Tricks or any other resource.

Resources:
Positioning: [Positioning](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/)
Inline vs Block: [Inline vs Block](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp)

So your styling should be something like this:

```
  p {

  display:inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 3vh;
  left:5vw;

  font-family : Times New Roman;
  font-weight : bold;
  font-size : 18px;
  color : #25374C;
  color : rgb(37, 55, 76);

  transform: rotate(270deg);


  text-decoration: none;

}
```

Comment: thank you this worked! ive made some changes to the values of bottom and left to suit my preferences. by the way, do you know how to add a vertical line under the hyperlink i just created? i did .vl {
  border-left: 4px solid #25374C;
  height: 300px;
}

Comment: let me guess what you mean, If you want to add a line under the hyperlink, you should enclose it with a div tag and then use the border-bottom property, then after you rotate it using transform property it should become vertical, or you can simply use another div tag to play with CSS using the width and height properties until it looks like the line you want, but I personally prefer the first solution as it's more effiecient.

Comment: Let me give you a Stackoverflow tip, try to be as clear as possible in your questions by providing visualizations of your current problem VS your desired results alongside your snippets of code, so that people can help you efficiently because it is difficult to imagine and guess problems in programming, good luck

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific on your question. I noticed your css is top:6px;

try to put bottom:6px; your position is relative (try absolute) as well or

transform-origin: bottom left 0px;

I am not sure if this answer your question but hopefully this can help. You usually put the div or your paragraph at the bottom part of your html so it is at the bottom part. I am really guessing on what you want to happen but if you give more specifics I will be able to help you on what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this lines

```
.socials-email a {
        font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: #25374C;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 1%;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```